# kinetic energy interation

Tags: integration

I was reading the following article http://www.askamathematician.com/2015/03/q-why-does-kinetic-energy-increase-as-velocity-squared/ I don't understand the math of the explanation at the final of the article. The author explain what he is using on every step, for example if it is the chain rule. My question is how he changed the interval of integration from D to T. Also how he changed the v(x) to v(t). I tried the u-substitution but I don't get how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that step he used substitution $x=x(t)$. When using change of variable, you change the integration interval to the interval of the new variable. The original interval on the position $x$ is $[0,D]$. The new interval on time $t$ is $[0,T]$. Strictly speaking, he should have changed $a(x)$ to $a(x(t))$. But since the acceleration function $a$ is not specified, he just used $a(t)$ to represent the acceleration at time $t$.